# Proper program structure using g_main_loop

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I have an application that requires use of callback functions that will not fire unless the glib g_main_loop is running. I am hazy on what a "good" program would look like implementing this, or what the expected program flow would be. I dont feel what I have seems correct because this method requires looping after every function that is asycn, to wait for the response. I would imagine there must be some way to spawn off the g_main_loop without it blocking, but Im not aware of how to achieve that.

Here is pseudo-code for what I have to achieve usage of the function requiring callback:

```
// declared globally so it can be started from main, stopped from callback.
GMainLoop *loop;

void callback_function(void)
{
  g_main_loop_quit(loop);
}

int main (void)
{
  func_which_requires_callback(callback_function);

  loop = g_main_loop_new();
  
  // loop will end when callback ends the loop

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In Event-Driven Programming, you don't wait.  The response should be a new event which triggers a later callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode is pretty much right. All the work is done in callbacks, while the main loop iterates. The callbacks are either triggered by asynchronous operations, or event sources such as `g_idle_add()`, or they are signal handlers.